# Tiling the plane being too repetitive

Tags: rendering, mesh, edit-mode, procedural, tilesize

Does anyone know of any tips to tile a plane without it being really repetitive? I'm trying to make a big ocean. I am following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CwJrb3vjAaA, but the way he does it isn't working. [image]

Comment: maybe this will answer: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cZfWXvNXp6Q

Comment: no im tiling the ocean sim onto the circle.

Comment: I would not use image textures for water. Textures will always look repetive over large scales. Instead, you might try combining glass and transparent shaders and use a noise texture to add waves.

Comment: @Jonas Could you clarify? How would I do that?

Comment: and how could I incorporate it into the tutorial stated in the question? @Jonas